# What is the `nonisolated` keyword in Swift?

Tags: swift, actor

I recently came across the `nonisolated` keyword in Swift in the following code:

```
actor BankAccount {

    init(balance: Double) {
        self.balance = balance
    }

    private var balance: Double

    nonisolated func availableCountries() -> [String] {
        return ["US", "CA", "NL"]
    }

    func increaseBalance(by amount: Double) {
        self.balance += amount
    }

}
```

What does it do? The code compiles both with and without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `nonisolated` keyword was introduced in [SE-313](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0313-actor-isolation-control.md). It is used to indicate to the compiler that the code inside the method is not accessing (either reading or writing) any of the mutable state inside the actor. This in turn, enables us to call the method from non-async contexts.

The `availableCountries()` method can be made `nonisolated` because it doesn't depend on any mutable state inside the actor (for example, it doesn't depend on the `balance` variable).

When you are accessing different methods or variables of an `actor`, from outside the actor, you are only able to do so from inside an asynchronous context.

Let's remove the `nonisolated` keyword from the `availableCountries()` method. Now, if we want to use the method, we are only allowed to do so in an async context. For example, inside a `Task`:

```
let bankAccount = BankAccount(balance: 1000)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Task {

        let availableCountries = await bankAccount.availableCountries()
        print(availableCountries)

    }

}
```

If we try to use the method outside of an async context, the compiler gives us errors:

[image: Compiler Error]

However, the `availableCountries()` isn't using any mutable state from the actor. Thus, we can make it `nonisolated`, and only then we can call it from non async contexts (and the compiler won't nag).

[image]